# Hide ProcessMonitor from ThemIda

Tags: process-monitor

I use the same computer for playing a game while working.

For my work i need to use ProcessMonitor from Microsoft.

Problem is that the game is "protected" with ThemIda and it won't start when ProcessMonitor is already running or will "crash" as soon as i start ProcessMonitor after starting the game.

Is there any way to prevent it from beeing "detected"?